# How do I tell from a module’s CPAN page whether it is in the core distribution?

Tags: perl, perl-module, cpan, perl-core

For example, when going through the [Time::HiRes documentation on search.cpan.org](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Time%3A%3AHiRes), is there some indication in the page itself the module is now part of Perl core distribution? I know I can usually find that out with some googling, but I'm trying to know if there’s an easier way.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`corelist`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?corelist).

```
>corelist Time::HiRes

Data for 2013-06-21
Time::HiRes was first released with perl v5.7.3
```

Also try `corelist -a Time::HiRes`

Comment: Even though I was looking for some indicator in the CPAN page itself, this is a far better way, with backwards compatibility info which is crucial for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Web site [corelist](http://perlpunks.de/corelist/) is a web interface to [Module::CoreList](https://metacpan.org/module/Module%3a%3aCoreList) like the command line tool with the same name.  Like the command line tool, the web interface is able to compare two Perl versions for modules that have been added, removed and/or updated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a list of the standard modules installed with Perl, see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodlib.html#Standard-Modules

Answer (score -1):

Not directly, but you can get fairly close.

Open [perlmodlib](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodlib.html) in another browser tab or run `perldoc perlmodlib` in a shell window. Then search the perlmodlib documentation, particularly the [Standard Modules](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodlib.html#Standard-Modules) section, for the name of the module in question.